# Is there a NoSQL database that can effectively detect duplicate items?

Tags: mongodb, cassandra, couchdb, database, nosql

I'm looking to implement a system that searches for duplicate entries before saving new entries, mostly by IP address.  Since NoSQL databases have eventual consistency, this doesn't seem like a natural use case.  Is there a way to make it work?

Comment: Not all NoSQL DBs have eventual consistency... Which one are you using?

Comment: Eventual consistency exists in relational data stores as well.  MySql replication, for example, is **not** always up to date.  There most certainly exists replication lag.  The argument would obviously be that you are inserting into the master, not the slaves, so said lag does not matter.  That would be the same answer for DB's like MongoDB.  Eventual consistency matters more for reads in this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CouchDB enforces uniqueness within _id field of the document. Here's and excerpt from http://guide.couchdb.org

Within a CouchDB database, each document must have a unique _id field. If you require unique values in a database, just assign them to a document’s _id field and CouchDB will enforce uniqueness for you.

There’s one caveat, though: in the distributed case, when you are running more than one CouchDB node that accepts write requests, uniqueness can be guaranteed only per node or outside of CouchDB. CouchDB will allow two identical IDs to be written to two different nodes. On replication, CouchDB will detect a conflict and flag the document accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for helping me understand the issue.  To clarify, in my case a "duplicate" entry has to be detected by more than unique fields.  The spec isn't fully written yet so I'm still just gathering information.  I see now that I need to confine duplicate detection and writing to a single node, like I can with an RDBMS.  In VoltDB (not really NoSQL), all nodes supposedly have the same view of the data though.  Maybe I could use something like this?

Answer (score 0):

Every relational database and MongoDB supports unique indexes on data tables/collections preventing the insertion of duplicate data...why isn't that good enough?

Creating a unique index in MongoDB is straight forward. Trying to insert duplicate entries will raise an error (if you use safe mode enabled or checking the result
of the insertion operation).

Comment: Duplicate entries will be allowed in certain circumstances so I'll have to search for records before saving new ones.  Can I do this by confining writes to a main node?

Comment: Do I understand you correctly? You first read the record, then check for duplicates, then write. Duplicates are checked by IP address, enforced by application layer logic and you check uniqueness by IP address so even if these are separate transactions this is still going to be atomic...  I think every database on the planet supports this.

Comment: Sorry but ask your questions in a more consistent way in order to receive a proper answer

Comment: Gjorgji and Bryan helped clarify the question with their comments.  Thanks for your help.